# MakeWalk fails to retarget an animation with the rigify armature PitchiPoy Version

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify

I'm trying to load a BVH motion capture files onto a rigged character with makewalk using this tutorial :

[tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOGAx9urX2s)

I'm using the rigify armature PitchiPoy Version without modifications,to avoid problems,but it does not work. How can I fix it ? thanks.

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with a ManuelbastionLab rig. The problem is due to the armature having bones that cannot be mapped by MakeWalk.

To solve it I moved the extra bones (in this case the breast bones) onto another layer.
To do this go into edit mode select the bones to move, press<kbd>M</kbd> and select a layer that is invisible (this can be checked in the data tab).

[image]

The light grey layer with the dot will not be visible.

Then I imported the BVH without any trouble.

Comment: Hello. Did you use an armature with the head bones ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. The armature was a ManuelBastionLAB anime female rig.

Comment: Hello Marieto. Did you solved it? 
 I'm having the same problem and I would like to know if there is a way to get the pitchipoy armature targeted by mocap files without errors.

Comment: I think that the Rob's suggestions could work. Personally I gave up using the mocap tecnique,because it forces you to use standardized movements. I think it's better to manually set keyframes in the timeline...